# Drag and drop elements with touch support

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I try to implement a drag and drop interface on my website. There will be a list of elements on the left and about 15 places to move them on right. Then on a form submit, I will retrieve the elements in these places and get their attributes for back-end calculations. I found a plugin about it: [dhtmlgoodies](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-nodes/drag-drop-nodes-demo2.html)

It is exactly what I want to do, but unfortunately, it doesn't support touchscreens.

I found also the HTML5 Drag and Drop but most of the reviews were "stay away from it".

Is there any way to make it support touch or any other plugin that will work with the same way?

I found also JQuery UI [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) but I couldn't find any similar example with the first link.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery UI works for you on mouse-based browsers, take a look at [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). It enables touch-based events for jQuery UI and will allow you to use the Draggable and Sortable interactions.